# Tabularx behaves differently inside Tikz Node

Tags: latex, tabular, tikz

I've created a `tabularx` table that behaves differently when I put it inside a `Tikz` node.

My objective is to fully justify the text inside the cell. You will find my LaTeX code below. Sorry for butchering it a little, I'm far from being an expert.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-5pt}
\begin{document}

\section{Inside Tikz Node}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 
  

\node[text width=11.5cm] at (5.72, -4.5) {

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=2.2cm}X>{\hsize=9cm}X}

\footnotesize{2011} & \textbf{\footnotesize{Regional Co-Manager}} \\
& \textbf{\scriptsize{Dunder Mifflin, Scranton PA}}\\
& \footnotesize{A major part of Jim Halpert's character is his relationship with Pam Beesly, which is often the subject of office speculation. This is made worse by the fact that Pam was engaged to Roy Anderson, a Dunder Mifflin warehouse worker. Throughout the first two seasons, incidents such as Pam falling asleep on Jim's shoulder in "Diversity Day" and drunkenly kissing him in "The Dundies" show a possibility of the feelings being mutual; however, Pam never acts on them and she remains engaged to Roy.}\\
\\
\hspace{-3.075mm}$\bullet$\hspace{1.7mm}\footnotesize{2005} & \textbf{\footnotesize{Sales Representative}} \\
& \textbf{\scriptsize{Dunder Mifflin, Scranton PA}}\\
& \footnotesize{Jim has two brothers; Pete, who lives in Boston, and Tom, who lives in New Jersey. They are both characterized as sharing Jim's general love of pranks but have come across as unpleasant and they somewhat bully their little brother. While Pete and Tom have been seen in several episodes, portrayed by Tug Coker, and Blake Robbins, Larissa has never been seen on screen.}\\

\end{tabularx}
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{9cm}

\section{Outside Tikz Node}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=2.2cm}X>{\hsize=9cm}X}

\footnotesize{2011} & \textbf{\footnotesize{Regional Co-Manager}} \\
& \textbf{\scriptsize{Dunder Mifflin, Scranton PA}}\\
& \footnotesize{A major part of Jim Halpert's character is his relationship with Pam Beesly, which is often the subject of office speculation. This is made worse by the fact that Pam was engaged to Roy Anderson, a Dunder Mifflin warehouse worker. Throughout the first two seasons, incidents such as Pam falling asleep on Jim's shoulder in "Diversity Day" and drunkenly kissing him in "The Dundies" show a possibility of the feelings being mutual; however, Pam never acts on them and she remains engaged to Roy.}\\
\\
\hspace{-3.075mm}$\bullet$\hspace{1.7mm}\footnotesize{2005} & \textbf{\footnotesize{Sales Representative}} \\
& \textbf{\scriptsize{Dunder Mifflin, Scranton PA}}\\
& \footnotesize{Jim has two brothers; Pete, who lives in Boston, and Tom, who lives in New Jersey. They are both characterized as sharing Jim's general love of pranks but have come across as unpleasant and they somewhat bully their little brother. While Pete and Tom have been seen in several episodes, portrayed by Tug Coker, and Blake Robbins, Larissa has never been seen on screen.}\\

\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

TikZ nodes are not justified by default, but you can make them justified by using the `align=justify` key:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-5pt}
\begin{document}

\section{Inside Tikz Node}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 
  

\node[text width=11.5cm,align=justify] at (5.72, -4.5) {

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=2.2cm}X>{\hsize=9cm}X}

\footnotesize{2011} & \textbf{\footnotesize{Regional Co-Manager}} \\
& \textbf{\scriptsize{Dunder Mifflin, Scranton PA}}\\
& \footnotesize{A major part of Jim Halpert's character is his relationship with Pam Beesly, which is often the subject of office speculation. This is made worse by the fact that Pam was engaged to Roy Anderson, a Dunder Mifflin warehouse worker. Throughout the first two seasons, incidents such as Pam falling asleep on Jim's shoulder in "Diversity Day" and drunkenly kissing him in "The Dundies" show a possibility of the feelings being mutual; however, Pam never acts on them and she remains engaged to Roy.}\\
\\
\hspace{-3.075mm}$\bullet$\hspace{1.7mm}\footnotesize{2005} & \textbf{\footnotesize{Sales Representative}} \\
& \textbf{\scriptsize{Dunder Mifflin, Scranton PA}}\\
& \footnotesize{Jim has two brothers; Pete, who lives in Boston, and Tom, who lives in New Jersey. They are both characterized as sharing Jim's general love of pranks but have come across as unpleasant and they somewhat bully their little brother. While Pete and Tom have been seen in several episodes, portrayed by Tug Coker, and Blake Robbins, Larissa has never been seen on screen.}\\

\end{tabularx}
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{9cm}

\section{Outside Tikz Node}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=2.2cm}X>{\hsize=9cm}X}

\footnotesize{2011} & \textbf{\footnotesize{Regional Co-Manager}} \\
& \textbf{\scriptsize{Dunder Mifflin, Scranton PA}}\\
& \footnotesize{A major part of Jim Halpert's character is his relationship with Pam Beesly, which is often the subject of office speculation. This is made worse by the fact that Pam was engaged to Roy Anderson, a Dunder Mifflin warehouse worker. Throughout the first two seasons, incidents such as Pam falling asleep on Jim's shoulder in "Diversity Day" and drunkenly kissing him in "The Dundies" show a possibility of the feelings being mutual; however, Pam never acts on them and she remains engaged to Roy.}\\
\\
\hspace{-3.075mm}$\bullet$\hspace{1.7mm}\footnotesize{2005} & \textbf{\footnotesize{Sales Representative}} \\
& \textbf{\scriptsize{Dunder Mifflin, Scranton PA}}\\
& \footnotesize{Jim has two brothers; Pete, who lives in Boston, and Tom, who lives in New Jersey. They are both characterized as sharing Jim's general love of pranks but have come across as unpleasant and they somewhat bully their little brother. While Pete and Tom have been seen in several episodes, portrayed by Tug Coker, and Blake Robbins, Larissa has never been seen on screen.}\\

\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

[image]